# GoDaddy Code Signing Certificate - SPC to p12

Tags: ssl, air, adobe

So currently I'm trying to convert the .spc file that was provided from GoDaddy and convert it to a .p12 file so I can sign my Adobe AIR build. Can anyone help me out as to what the process is to complete this? Or maybe I'm going to wrong route on this?

Comment: SPC is a certificate itself, you should also have a private key separately. Then you can combine them.

Comment: I have been trying to do this as well.  The instructions I have found for doing this assume I am using windows.  Or the instructions are generating the CSR using keytool rather then openssl.  I used openssl (per instructions from GoDaddy); keytool makes a codesignstore that is used in later steps.  Because I used keytool, I don't have the codesignstore.  Hopefully I can figure it out and post an answer to your questions.